Can't delete Pinned custom folder
For individual Pinned items, one can right-click and select Unpin. However, for Pinned folders (created by dragging a Pinned item over another Pinned item) there is no right-click Unpin option.
Example Pinned folder - Video Converters:

How can I delete such a folder?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Moved the pinned items out of the group then delete each of the items.

Hi Ramhound, thanks so much. It's such a simple solution. Why didn't I think of that ......

@Ramhound, though simple, it's not intuitively obvious to the casual observer, and might mak a useful answer.
